# Filter R dataframe by checkbox in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to load a flat file into a Shiny app and let users filter it by some binary flag columns. I think I'm missing some understanding of the syntax.

I can get the function to run reactively and read the checkbox, but it breaks when I try to use that value to filter. This my server.R

```
library(shiny)

function(input, output, session) {

  all_data <- read.table("my_data_file.txt", head = TRUE)

  # apply checkbox filters
  filter_on_a_column <- reactive({
    ctr = 0
    if (input$checkbox_1){
      ctr = 1
    }
    ctr
  })
  
  ## This seems to work. I can see the text output change when I check or uncheck the box
  # output$text_output <- renderText(filter_on_a_column())
  
  ## This also seems to work. It prints out the number of rows when the test is explicit
  # current_data <- reactiveValues(selected = all_data[which(as.numeric(all_data$binary_flag_column) >= 1),])
  # output$text_output <- renderText(dim(current_data$selected)[1])

  # This line crashes the app
  current_data <- reactiveValues(selected = all_data[which(as.numeric(all_data$binary_flag_column) >= filter_on_a_column()),])
  output$text_output <- renderText(dim(current_data$selected)[1])
}
```

The ui.R is minimal

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    checkboxInput("checkbox_1", "Checkbox 1", FALSE),
    textOutput("text_output")
  )
)
```

The data file is a tsv with a header. The flag column doesn't have values other than 0 or 1 (e.g. no NA's)

```
ID  binary_flag_column
1   0
2   1
3   0
4   1
5   1
6   1
7   1
8   0
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example, i.e. example data and the `ui` part. I guess the problem is that `filter_on_a_column` is `NULL` before it is first initialised and this then breaks your comparison. You could use a `reactive` instead of `reactiveValues` for `current_data` and use `req(filter_on_a_column())` in this `reactive` to circumvent the problem

Comment: As suggested by @starja maybe try `current_data <- reactive({ all_data[which(as.numeric(all_data$binary_flag_column) >= filter_on_a_column()),]
})` and `output$text_output <- renderText(dim(current_data()[1]))`?